# Same result for two arrays of counters of different algorithms

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I'm trying to build up a program comparing number of strokes of  algorithms BFS, DFS, A* (which has two heuristics) on a game of fifteen.

My counter count the same result for the two arrays of counters of BFS and DFS and both A*. Yet, I'm using actually using four different arrays from a main (class Project) and I'm assigning four different variables for those strokes.

The part of the code that isn't right is, to my mind, a while loop which explores the son of a vertice as far as possible (for BFS) or discovering each following nodes (for BFS). The difference, which is of the utmost importance, is the last line of code which is either frontier.push(child);, for DFS, or frontier.add(child); for BFS.

Each time we enter the loop, the number of strokes is incremented

```
number_of_strokes_DFS+=1;
```

or

```
number_of_strokes_BFS+=1;
```

When we find the final state we add the result to the array of the number of strokes:

```
array_number_of_strokes_dfs.add(number_of_strokes_DFS);
```

or

```
array_number_of_strokes_bfs.add(number_of_strokes_BFS);
```

Here is the guilty code finally (actually only DFS as far as BFS is really a lookalike except the last line).

```
 while(!frontier.isEmpty()){
        number_of_strokes_DFS+=1;
     if(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime>10000)break;
     // We remove the current state from the frontier
     current_state = frontier.pop();
     // We get all possible actions from the current state
     actions = current_state.getActions();
     // We add the current state to already explored nodes
     explored_nodes.add(current_state);
     //System.out.println(current_state);
     path.add(current_state);

     // we found the goal
     if(goal_test(current_state)){
         /*for(State visited :path){
         System.out.println(visited);
     }*/
            array_number_of_strokes_dfs.add(number_of_strokes_DFS);
         System.out.println("nombres de coups DFS"+number_of_strokes_DFS);
         number_of_strokes_DFS=0;
         return current_state;
     }

     // We create every child
     for (Action action : actions){
         //System.out.println("action : " + action);
         // we get a child from the execution of the current_state
         State child = current_state.execute(action);
         //System.out.println("we executed the action");
         if(!explored_nodes.contains(child)&&!frontier.contains(child)){
             // This child not being already explored nor int the frontier we add it to the last one
             frontier.push(child);
         }
     }

 }
    array_number_of_strokes_dfs.add(-1);

    return finalState;

}
```

Here is the actual problem as far as when I let array_number_of_strokes_dfs.add(number_of_strokes_DFS);, for instance, I always get the same result as BFS in the array. It might happen once, but not every time!!!
Whereas if I add a zero

```
array_number_of_strokes_dfs.add(0);
```

I do see the difference...

Do you have any ideas?

Here are the result:

```
strokes BFS : [3, 27, 27, 26, 26, 2631, 7]
strokes DFS[3, 27, 27, 26, 26, 2631, 7]
```

Comment: What is the type of the `frontier`?

Comment: @Ishamael Hi! it is a Stack of State `Stack<State> frontier = new Stack<State>();` it is written a bit above the loop I showed within the algorithm function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `frontier` is a `Stack` or something similar, than `add` is analogous to `push`, so your `BFS` is in fact also doing a depth-first search. If you actually want to insert at the beginning (something you want to do if you `pop` elements on each iteration), you want to call `.add(0, elem)` (note the `0` -- the index at which to insert) instead of `.add(elem)`, so that it is actually inserted at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a similar question for two A* algorithms with the number of wrong tiles placed and Manhattan distance heuristics. Should I ask another question?

Comment: Just to be certain, it is DFS that has to search with the first found node and therefore has to use `.add(0, elem)`, isn't it?

Comment: Not in your case. Note that on each iteration you pop from the stack. Popping fetches the last element. For dfs you want new elements to be processed first, so you need to add them to the end (push). For bfs you want them to be processed last, so you need to add them to the beginning (add at position 0)

Comment: Regarding A*, the cause is likely to be different, so it makes sense to ask in a separate quotation

Comment: Okay, I will! I was wondering if using a queue with add and remove made sense for BFS?

Comment: Yes,  a queue with add and remove is more proper way to do it. Moreover it will speed up the algorithm drastically as it will become linear as opposed to quadratic. You dfs is already linear.

Comment: Ho? I didn't even knew these mathematical properties! 
May I provide you the link of my question about A*?